# Unable to pushViewController iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am using storyboard in my app, [image]:
I have Button in my `View`, On click of button i want to navigate to new `View`

But when i click on button nothing happens,

Here is my Code:

```
- (IBAction)JoinClicked:(id)sender{

    JoinWithViewController *detail_view_controller = [[JoinWithViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JoinWithViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail_view_controller animated:YES];
}
```

Where i am doing mistake , please help.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Are either of detail_view_controller or self.navigationController nil?

Comment: When i log this `NSLog(@"self.navigationController=%@ ---- detail_view_controller=%@ ",self.navigationController,detail_view_controller);` i got the output as this, `self.navigationController=(null) ---- detail_view_controller=<JoinWithViewController: 0xb814370>`

Comment: why you are not performiing segue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set storyboard id of view controller in story board in identity inspector

Make a reference to your storyboard like

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

then to your controller

```
YourController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourController"];// storyboardId

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

and you can also make segue and do

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:sender/nil];
```

Comment: Shows no knows class method for selector `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: do this
JoinWithViewController *detail_view_controller = (JoinWithViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardId];

Comment: `JoinWithViewController` is `.xib` file

Comment: its really confusing you are using storyboard and then you are also making xib files, and you want to push: when the favorites view is not in a navigationController

Comment: If i don't use `.xib` and if i want click event of button on `favoritesTab` (if button is there on `favoritesTab`) then how wil i get ?

Comment: well i highly recommend use storyboard from now on, follow some tutorials on the web. here is how you can easily navigate in storyboard, see the storyboard
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v70zdggir0rxdnq/CouponRaja%202.zip

Answer (score 1):

Make an identifier for your push-segue in storyboard.

then use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

When using story boards you should use segues for as much navigation as possible.

Answer (score 1):

use this one :

> ```
> - (IBAction)JoinClicked:(id)sender{
>
> [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"JoinWithIdentifier" sender: self];
> ```
>
> }

and add segue in storyborad like 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, please verify your outlets correctly configured or not in xib or storyboard.

Edit:
         You are using storyboard and wants the xib file to get pushed onto your view controller if I am not wrong, you can drag another view controller in storyboard and name it JoinWithViewController and push using segue on button click. That is much easier than what your trying to do here.

Comment: you can load xib using the code : [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JoinWithViewController" owner:self options:nil]; i doubt this approach will work, better use storyboard.

Comment: yes i am able to load `Old.xib` but unable to push to new view or new `new.xib` after loading `Old.xib`