# Different ViewControllers according to ios versions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, versioning

I have an `UICollectionViewController` into `TabBarViewController` that works for `iOS 6.0` and later ios versions. I would like to know if there is any way to use a different `ViewController` if a device has elder than `iOS 6.0` version. For example, can i use a `UITableView` for devices that use prior version than `iOS 6.0` and `UICollection` for devices that use `iOS 6.0` and posterior versions?

I also tried `PSTCollectionView` but it has some problems.

I added an image that shows my storyboard. My collection is in TabBarController and i want to change to TableView if a device uses prior to iOS 6.0 .[image]

Comment: Please use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/1091539, its the best answer for this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check iPhone iOS Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

Comment: @Mutawe i checked this before post this question. But i do not know the way that i handle different controllers into TabbarViewController according to version. This is what i really want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very simple solution to it

For Example In your tabBarControllers index 2 is for CollectionView and on 3 is for TableViewController

simply do all required settings icons names etc in storyboard

now in your ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWith Options do this

As I assume your tabbarController is rootViewContrller do this

```
UITabbarController *tabbarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NSMutableArray *arrayControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabbarController.viewControllers];
if (OlderVersion) {//Check
    [arrayControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
}else{
    [arrayControllers removeObjectAtIndex:3];
}
[tabbarController setViewControllers:arrayControllers];
```

Comment: Thank you Raheel.This will work.So if my tabBarController is not the rootViewController i have to do this in viewWillAppear method?

Comment: dont get the scenario, but if you tabbarController is not the rootViewController then get it by StoryBoard Id, first set the ID in storyBoard in Identity Inspector then

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];

    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarControllerStoryBoardId"];// storyboardId

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Just get the version of the phone with this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

And then, load the right view controller depending on the value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know how to check the version of ios that a device uses but i would like to know how to handle the controllers in storyboard

Comment: Use performSegue according to the versions

Comment: My CollectionViewController is connected with another screen in storyboard.Can i design another disconnected ViewController for the elder versions in storyboard and call it somewhere in the code?

Comment: @RaheelSadiq i dont know how to do this cause my collection is in TabBarViewController that it has its own segues.

Comment: @hoya21 I dont know the design of your storyBoard but if you are uncomfortable with segues, then make storyBoard reference to that ViewController and push/present modal as you like. See this, for reference for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700439/unable-to-pushviewcontroller-ios/19700584#19700584

Comment: and it doesn't matter if your controller is in tabBar just perform the segue in storyBoard as desired

Comment: @RaheelSadiq I reedited my question and added an image of my storyboard to see the segue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42479/discussion-between-hoya21-and-raheelsadiq)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add identifier to your view controller

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
if(versionValue>=7)
{
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIOS7"];
}
else
{
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIOS6"];
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for your time. Can you tell me where i have to use this, cause my ViewController is in TabBarViewController?

Comment: You should use it when you create TabBarViewController, when you add collection view to tab bar. I assume you use storyboard but to make this work you have to refactor the code and you have to do it programatically.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can do that with checking following condition for your version.

```
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

    float versionValue=[currSysVer floatvalue];

    if(versionValue>=6)
    {
        // do some stuff you want to do here
    }
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Manthan. Can you help me in which part of the code can i do this cause my UICollectionViewController is in a TabBarViewController?

Comment: The `systemVersion` is a float value !!